# Add new picklist value for salesforce standard field programmatically

Tags: apex, custom-object, standard-objects, trigger

In my application i have a custom field called **Column__c**, what i want is when i create a new Column__c record, the Column__c Name will be added automatically in the status picklist field in **Task Standard object**. By default status field has (Not Started, In Progress, Completed, Waiting on, someone else, Deferred). is it possible to add new picklist value for status field via trigger/programmatically? anyone is willing to help will be appreciated , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not without using the Metadata API, such as [FinancialForce's Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). However, it really shouldn't matter, since you can store whatever value you want in a pick list, so long as "enforce pick list values" is not enabled. Simply have your trigger assign whatever value you choose, and that record will retain that record, even if it's not on the list of accepted values.

Comment: yes.. you are correct but why is it my custom status value inserted was deleted automatically in a period of time ? "For the picklist Task Status on object Task, the value hhaha was deleted." (salesforce emailed me that message recently)

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio That's new. I might need to do some research on that.

Comment: thanks i will make a research too .. please beep me if you find an answer.. thanks

Comment: by the way.. how will we create a task object to a custom object.. For my custom object , i want to create a lookup field for task standard object..

Comment: oh don't worry .. salesforce emailed that it was deleted. but when i query the status in task .. the "hhaha" value i inserted was there..